# using codelite with scons

Tags: c++, netbeans-7, scons, codelite

How difficult is to use codelite on top of a scons project?

what features i should expect to lose? is there a way to configure codelite to use the scons configuration files to keep track of the project files.

At the moment i'm using Netbeans 7.1, but the tool doesn't scale well with complex projects like LLVM. I'm curious with codelite as it seems to have a very good code completion architecture (relying on the llvm clang plugin) but i'm not sure how hard will it be to migrate my project (based on scons) to it

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anything about codelite, but eclipse is an excellent IDE with code completion like you mention. There is an SCons plugin available for eclipse called [SConsolidator](http://www.scons.org/wiki/EclipsePlugin).

I have found that eclipse has excellent support for C++ and Python.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?
[image: scons codelite]

But codelite is old-school IDE with very poor functional, like Visual Studio 6. I recommend use Eclipse CDT.